# How to implement login using Google, Facebook and Github in website made with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, backend

I am making a project in PHP and MYSQL and i want to implement login using Google,Facebook and Github, i am a complete beginner and can't seem to figure it out, any help will be appreciated.

I have tried google's https://console.cloud.google.com/ but it only has an option for google login.

Answer (score 1):

## Google

Read this article: https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-google-api-using-php/

```
 • Go to the Google API Console.
 • Select an existing project from the projects list, or click NEW PROJECT to create a new project:
 • Enter the Project Name.
 • Under the Project Name, you will see the Google API console automatically creates a project ID. Optionally you can change this project ID by the Edit link. But project ID must be unique worldwide.
 • Click on the CREATE button and the project will be created in some seconds.
 • Select OAuth consent screen from the left side navigation panel, and specify the consent screen settings.
 • Set User Type to External, and CREATE.
 • Provide app information, SAVE AND CONTINUE.
 • You can skip the Scopes settings, SAVE AND CONTINUE.
 • In the Test users setting, add users with gmail addresses.
 • While the publishing status is set to “Testing”, only test users are able to access this app.
 • SAVE AND CONTINUE
 • Select the Credentials from the left side navigation panel, click the CREATE CREDENTIALS drop-down and select OAuth client ID.
 • In the Application type section, select Web application.
 • In the Authorized redirect URIs field, enter the redirect URL.
 • Click the CREATE button.
```

The article recommends you to have a table like the one below:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `oauth_provider` enum('google','facebook','twitter','linkedin') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'google',
    `oauth_uid` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `gender` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `locale` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `picture` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `created` datetime NOT NULL,
    `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

You can add github there as well as a possible `oauth_provider`.

You of course will need to have the client ID and secret properly added to your application, read this for more information: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

## Facebook

Read this article: https://www.codexworld.com/login-with-facebook-using-php/

To access Facebook API you need to create a Facebook App and specify the App ID & App Secret at the time of calling the Facebook API. Follow the step-by-step guide to create Facebook App and generate App ID & Secret in the Facebook Developers Dashboard.

```
 • Go to the Facebook for Developers page and log in with your Facebook account.
 • Click the My Apps link at the top navigation bar and select Add New App.
 • Enter the Display Name and Contact Email.
 • Click on the Create App ID button.
 • You will be redirected to the App Dashboard.
 • Navigate to the Settings » Basic page.
 • Specify the App Domains and select the Category of your App.
 • Click the Save Changes.
 • Navigate to the Add a Product page by clicking the PRODUCTS(+) link at the left navigation menu panel.
 • Select Facebook Login to Set Up.
 • Select Web as the App platform.
 • Enter the Site URL and Save.
 • Navigate to the Facebook Login » Settings page.
 • In the Valid OAuth Redirect URIs field, enter the Redirect URL.
 • Click the Save Changes.
```

You will therefore need to create a Facebook app, add its credentials to your application so Facebook SDK will work, which you need to integrate into it. This article suggests the creation of a table described in the previous section.

## GitHub

You can use a library from here: https://github.com/topics/php-login

Basically you, as always need to look on what resources provide partial or full solution to your problem and integrate it into your project. This one appears to be promising: https://github.com/msaad1999/PHP-Login-System

According to this article: https://www.binarytides.com/php-add-login-with-github-to-your-website/

you will need to register your website with GitHub Oauth and it provides this code for log in:

```
function signup_github()
{
    $client_id = 'your_client_id';
    $redirect_url = 'your_callback_url';
    
    //login request
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
    {
        $url = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=$client_id&amp;redirect_uri=$redirect_url&amp;scope=user";
        header("Location: $url");
    }
}
```

and this one for signup:

```
public function signup_github()
{
    $client_id = 'your_client_id;
    $redirect_url = 'your_callback_url';
    
    //get request , either code from github, or login request
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET')
    {
        //authorised at github
                if(isset($_GET['code']))
        {
            $code = $_GET['code'];
            
            //perform post request now
            $post = http_build_query(array(
                'client_id' => $client_id ,
                'redirect_uri' => $redirect_url ,
                'client_secret' => 'your_client_secret',
                'code' => $code ,
            ));
            
            $context = stream_context_create(array("http" => array(
                "method" => "POST",
                "header" => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencodedrn" .
                            "Content-Length: ". strlen($post) . "rn".
                            "Accept: application/json" ,  
                "content" => $post,
            ))); 
            
            $json_data = file_get_contents("https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token", false, $context);
            
            $r = json_decode($json_data , true);
            
            $access_token = $r['access_token'];
            
            $url = "https://api.github.com/user?access_token=$access_token";
            
            $data =  file_get_contents($url);
            
            //echo $data;
            $user_data  = json_decode($data , true);
            $username = $user_data['login'];
            
            
            $emails =  file_get_contents("https://api.github.com/user/emails?access_token=$access_token");
            $emails = json_decode($emails , true);
            $email = $emails[0];
            
            $signup_data = array(
                'username' => $username ,
                'email' => $email ,
                'source' => 'github' ,
            );
            
            signup_login_user($signup_data);
        }
        else
        {
            $url = "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=$client_id&amp;redirect_uri=$redirect_url&amp;scope=user";
            header("Location: $url");
        }
    }
}
```

## Summary

Your question is definitely not easy and it is also composite. My answer will not work for you out-of-the-box. It merely gives you a starting point for all three sub-problems so you will know how to break down your task into subtasks and how to approach them.